# how to iterate through functions with button press in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning swift and building an ARApp but can't seem to understand how to iterate through a few functions with every separate button press. I have created 3 func with animation built in and want to press the button once and funcAnimation#1 activate then tap button again to proceed to funcAnimation#2 and so forth.

```
@IBAction func nextAnimation(_ sender: UIButton) {
funcAnimation#1()
funcAnimation#2()
funcAnimation#3()
}
```

of course the problem here is that they all activate at once. I would like to iterate only on button press for each individual press. In addition I would also like to have a backButton that reverses the current animation to previous animation. I read in Apple's documentation that there is a addTarget method but I don't understand how it works or how to implement it. Please Help!

Comment: Use one counter (integer) argument which increment every time on button tap. Add one condition to set that counter to zero when it reaches to limit (ie. 3)

Comment: You could also use completion handlers. Once a function finishes running, it runs the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should like this :

```
// You can define this variable globally...
var counter = 0
@IBAction func nextAnimation(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        funcAnimation1()
        // Increase counter count by 1 and you can add this line to completion of animation.
       // You can also disable your button interaction until your animation gets complete and that way you can handle your UI
        count += 1
    }
    else if (counter == 1) {
        funcAnimation2()
         // Increase counter count by 1 and you can add this line to completion of animation.
        count += 1
    }
    else if (counter == 2) {
        funcAnimation3()
        // set your counter to 0 again to loop through your animation.
        counter = 0
    }
}
```

Your Back Action should look like this:

```
@IBAction func backAnimation(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        funcAnimation1()
        // set your counter to 2 again to loop through your animation.
        count = 2
    }
    else if (counter == 1) {
        funcAnimation2()
        // decrease counter count by 1 and you can add this line to completion of animation.
        // You can also disable your button interaction until your animation gets complete and that way you can handle your UI
        count -= 1
    }
    else if (counter == 2) {
        funcAnimation3()
       // decrease counter count by 1 and you can add this line to completion of animation.
        count -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You can disable the button after tap to complete the first animation and the second, then third just like that. It's all on you how you want to handle you UI flow.

Comment: Thank you Jarvis, this worked great. and the animations occur individually on every button press. I have another quick question. I have two separate buttons, one "next" which applies the animations and one "back". Is there a way to reverse the current state of the animation to the previous animation? so let's say that you're on animation #3 and on "back" button it goes automatically to previous animation state #2?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by checking on Back button. decrease your counter by 1 in it and play the animation. but there is one breaking condition don't decrease your counter if counter == 0. Reset it to 2.

Comment: @Sam I have updated my answer for your back button action.

Comment: the back action does register that I'm pressing the back button and it is in theory applying that change but it is not reversing the animation. Since the animation has already happened when the "next" button was pressed then you don't see anything but your answer is registering in the console. I'm using SCNTransaction for the animation but there doesn't seem to be a .reversed method. I will continue to research that but I think that is another topic. I don't want to abuse your time. Your answers did help and were spot on. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam Thanks, You can checkout UIViewPropertyAnimator for having control over your animation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way!

Just set tag of button 1 *(Ex. `btnObj.tag=1`)*

And manage method(s) in action of the button like

My suggestion is also manage `flag` for animation like if 1st animation is in process then 2nd will be waiting for finish and after finishing 1st animation, button will be clicked so your animation will not mismatch.

```
var isAnimated = false;
@IBAction func myAnimationMethod(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isAnimated {return} // Or display appropriate message by alert
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        isAnimated=true
        funcAnimation1(...Your Code... After finish to set isAnimated=false)
        sender.tag = 2 
    }
    else if (sender.tag  == 2) {
       isAnimated=true
        funcAnimation2(...Your Code... After finish to set isAnimated=false)
        sender.tag = 3 
    }
    else if (sender.tag  == 3) {
         isAnimated=true
        funcAnimation3(...Your Code... After finish to set isAnimated=false)
        sender.tag = 1 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can forward your animations and go back to previous animation state through a back button like this .

Step 1 : Declare two integer type variables

```
var tapCount = 0 //For forwarding your animations from first to third
var currentAnimation = 0 // For reversing the animation from current animation
```

Step 2 : In your IBAction Function

```
    @IBAction func nextAnimation(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if tapCount == 0
        {
            if currentAnimation == 1
            {
                Animation2()
            }
            else
            {
                Animation1()
            }
            tapCount += 1

        }
        else if tapCount == 1
        {
            if currentAnimation == 2
            {
                Animation3()
            }
            else
            {
                Animation2()
            }
            tapCount += 1
        }
        else if tapCount == 2
        {
            if currentAnimation == 3
            {
                Animation1()
            }
            else
            {
                Animation3()
            }
            tapCount = 0
        }
    }
```

Step 3 : In your functions

```
    func Animation1()  {
        currentAnimation = 1
       print("First Animation")
    }
    func Animation2()  {
        currentAnimation = 2
         print("Second Animation")
    }
    func Animation3()  {
        currentAnimation = 3
     print("third Animation")
    }
```

Step 4: Lastly For Reversing the animation from current state

```
@IBAction func backAnimation(_ sender: Any)
{
    if currentAnimation == 2
    {
         Animation1()

    }
    else if currentAnimation == 3
    {
        Animation2()

    }
    else
    {

    }
    tapCount = 0
}
```

Hope it helps !!

For **addTarget(_:action:for:)** method , this can be done without connecting a **IBAction** and declaring it in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad as required.It will Associates a target object and action method with the control.

For example :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. nextAnimation), for: .touchUpInside) //Declared outlet as nextButton
            backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. backAnimation), for: .touchUpInside) //Declared outlet as backButton and this adds a target
        }
    @objc func nextAnimation(sender: UIButton) {
       // Do your stuff for next animation
    }
   @objc func backAnimation(sender: UIButton) {
       // Do your stuff for previous animation
    }
```